# Inheritance and Interface segregation principle

Tags: c#, inheritance, solid-principles, interface-segregation-principle

Does inheritance from a class with unused methods violates the interface segregation principle?

For example:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public void Receive(int n)
    {
        // . . . (some important work)

        OnMsg(n.ToString());
    }

    protected abstract void OnMsg(string msg);
}

class Concrete : Base
{
    protected override void OnMsg(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Msg: " + msg);
    }
}
```

`Concrete` depends on method `Base.Receive(int n)`, but it never uses it.

**UPD**

Definition I use:

> ISP states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it
>   does not use.

Comment: I'm not sure that in this example that it doesn't use it, how would OnMsg ever be called if Receive is not used?

Comment: In my case the only way to call `OnMsg` is from `Receive`. I need this inheritance to project incoming data (`int n`) to `Concrete`'s interface which uses `string msg`. In real example there's some more complex work than just `ToString()`

Comment: @astef: As Paulo rightly pointed out, you are using the `template design pattern` here :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting what the interface segregation principle says. In your case you're fine and are not "forcing" any implementation. In fact you're applying the [Template method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

If you had a hypothetical

```
interface ICommunicateInt
{
  int Receive();
  void Send(int n);
}
```

in order to implement it, your `Base` class would be forced to implement a `Send` method that it does not need.
So, the ISP suggests that it is better to have:

```
interface ISendInt
{
  void Send(int n);
}

interface IReceiveInt
{
  int Receive();
}
```

so your classes can choose to implement one or both. Also methods in other classes that need a class that can send an Int, can require a

```
void Test(ISendInt snd)
// void Test(ICommunicateInt snd) // Test would "force" snd to depend on 
                                  // a method that it does not use
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that Concrete "depends" upon Base.Receive() in the way I would use the term. How would Concrete need to change if Receive were modified? I would argue, not at all. Suppose we replaced Receive() with a method of a different name or with a different signature, Concrete would be unaware. Does Concrete call Receive()? No. So I see no dependency on Receive() here.

The dependency is with the signature OnMsg(), Concrete participates in very particular relationship with Base, fulfilling that OnMsg() contract.

But in a different sense Concrete very much depends on Base.Receive(), which is it's interface to the outside world - without that method no-one can access Concrete's capabilties. In this sense Concrete "uses" Base.Receive() at a very fundamental level.

Comment: I understand you. But what's the answer? Is it bad way to project unknown incoming data to a target interface?

Comment: No it's not bad, it's a fundamentally important pattern.